# Why we need to include quotation mark when inserting string variable to mysql database php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$string = 'Loreum';
$insert = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2 ) VALUES ($string , 7)";
$conn -> query($insert)
```

This will produce an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ashfjksaf' in 'field list'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\yipee.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\yipee.php(23): PDO->query('INSERT INTO yea...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\yipee.php on line 23
```

However when I change to

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO table (field1, field2 ) VALUES ('$string' , 7)";
```

It works as expected.I wonder why we need to include single quotation mark in the string variable.I thought we only need to include quotation mark on literal string.

Comment: if you place a php variable between single quote marks, the compiler will use the variable. If you don't use it, due of doublequoted string, it will handle the $string as $string, not what it holds.

Comment: You wouldn't need to include the quotation marks if you used [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Which you should do anyway as a security measure. To answer your question, when you put `$string` into the query string, its value *becomes a string literal*. Try printing out `$insert` afterwards to see what query is actually being sent to the DB...

Comment: Think about it: what if you said `$string = 'Loreum, something else';`?  What would `$insert` look like then?

Comment: This is predefined syntax of mysql to use quotes for strings and php variables containing string value.And any string without quotes is treated like table field's name

Comment: Same as in PHP, strings need to be quoted, so the engine would understand it. $var = bla or $var = bla() will be refered either as constant or function. Not quoted string in most of the cases is understood by MySQL as a column name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the MySQL syntax works. PHP is merely constructing the query for you.

PHP will replace $string with the Loreum

so the MySQL query will look like this

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2 ) VALUES (Loreum , 7)
```

which is invalid syntax.

Therefore the quotation marks need to be added.

Comment: any reference so that i can know more about it?

Comment: @dramasea: what specifically do you want to know? It's SQL syntax 101, string literals need to be wrapped in quotes to be interpreted as *string literals*.

Comment: I mean is there any site I can reference to so that I cab know more about sql syntax

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: http://www.google.com ? More seriously (?), as suggested above  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/#manual is the ultimate reference for MySQL SQL syntax. http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_quickref.asp is probably more accessible at first. But ... well ... there are *tons* of documentation about SQL on the web. It shouldn't be so hard to found some using *your favorite* search engine ;)

Answer (score 0):

all  mysql   string  should be  in single  quote

like

```
               insert into table_name   (name,email)values('alok','alok@gmail.com');
```