# Ajax PHP Scope issues

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm having some problems connecting to my functions and database from an ajax call in a form.

```
<?php require_once("../includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("../includes/validation_functions.php"); ?>
<?php include("../includes/layouts/header.php"); ?>


<form action="Assets/ajax/userdetails.php" id="ajax-user" method="post">
    <div class="well" style="border-color: #b81e1e; display: none;" id="details1">
        <div>
            <label for="FirstName">First Name:<br /></label>
            <input name="FirstName" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="LastName">Last Name:<br /></label>
            <input name="LastName" type="text"  />
        </div>
        <div>
            <select name="gender">
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <input class="btn btn-hero right" type="submit">

    </div>
</form>

<?php include("../includes/layouts/footer.php"); ?>
```

Javascript Looks like this;

```
$(document).on("submit", "form#ajax-user", function() {

    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr("action"),
        type = that.attr("method"),
        data = {};


    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;

    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }

    });

    return false;
});
```

I've got the ajax running on submit which is fine. Then it's to run the php, but I keep getting an error;

**Warning**:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in **/home/public/Assets/ajax/userdetails.php** on line **12**

And lastly the php called looks as follows, I assume it's something to do with the scope, but I'm still learning and been struggling with this for a couple of days, if anyone could give me some pointers it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['FirstName'], $_POST['LastName'], $_POST['gender'])) {

    $current_user = $_SESSION["admin_id"];
    $firstname = $_POST['FirstName'];
    $lastname = $_POST['LastName'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    $query = "UPDATE users SET FirstName = '$firstname', LastName = '$lastname', Gender = '$gender' WHERE id = $current_user";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    }
?>
```

**EDIT**

$connection is defined in db_connection;

```
<?php
    define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "****");
    define("DB_PASS", "****");
    define("DB_NAME", "****");
  // 1. Create a database connection
  $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
  // Test if connection succeeded
  if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . 
         mysqli_connect_error() . 
         " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
  }
?>
```

Comment: Hope i've given enough info here, apologies if this is an obvious error!

Comment: How do you define `$connection` ?

Comment: Check Edited answer as per your edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have invlid/dont have connection  syntax as per mysqli.

Use it like:

```
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","Uname","PWD","DBName");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error(), mysqli_connect_errno());
}
```

**Update**

As per your edited Question:

Use `<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>`
inside your userdetails.php. As you need $connection parameter.

Comment: **Dont** use path `<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>`  **as it is** because path will depend on your folder structure. I mean include that `db_connection` file in your userdetails.php as per your folder path.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Amendments made as advised. I really appreciate all the guidance and volumes of knowledge of users on this site.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by the others, you need to set the connection first. Moreover, your query string lacks single quotation marks around the $current_user variable:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET FirstName = '$firstname', LastName = '$lastname', Gender = '$gender' WHERE id = '$current_user'";
```

Comment: Double quotes around the statement mean that PHP is already interpreting it for variables, so the single quotes wont make a difference in this case.  They can be left out altogether.

Comment: @MichaelDoye , yes but you see Single quotes (`'`) make  the variable Stiring type , like for say firstname,lastname. You can avoid single quote Only for numeric value like Id getting ?

Comment: @MichaelDoye, see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171615/why-we-need-to-include-quotation-mark-when-inserting-string-variable-to-mysql-da

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to define the $connection

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['FirstName'], $_POST['LastName'], $_POST['gender'])) {

$current_user = $_SESSION["admin_id"];
$firstname = $_POST['FirstName'];
$lastname = $_POST['LastName'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$connection = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));
$query = "UPDATE users SET FirstName = '$firstname', LastName = '$lastname', Gender = '$gender' WHERE id = $current_user";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

?>

Comment: First: seems that OP defined the `$connection` using `<?php require_once("../includes/db_connection.php"); ?>`. Next: Your code does not have the right to work, as you're using pure strings inside `mysqli_connect`